# How can I make Crytal Report's Header title reflect User's Selection from web app?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am not a Crystal Reports person; the individual that does Crystal report writing for us is on a two-week vacation and the users need some urgent changes made.

I have managed to make the changes that I could but I am stuck.

The other change that I am not able to handle is to show as header title users's selection.

For instance, on our web app, we have a dropdownlistbox with 3 options, Education Task Force (ETF), Court Review Board(CRB) and Conflict Resolution Group (CRG).

If a user selects ETF from the dropdownlist, the Crystal Reports report header needs to read `Education Task Force`

If a user selects CRB, the report header should read `Court Review Board` and if the selection from the web app is CRG, the report should read `Conflict Resolution Group`

Is this possible?

Thanks a lot in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a formula and put it in the report header

```
select {?YourParameter}
case "ETF" : "Education Task Force"
case "CRB" : "Court Review Board"
case "CRG" : "Conflict Resolution Group"
default : "Unknown"
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Ryan. Sorry if I am asking you to hold my hand here but do I click on the report header, right-click on formula, click new formula and put the code in there? You also said {?YourParameter}, does the report parameter have to be any particular name or just name of my choosing?

Comment: Your report is being filtered by the drop-down so the parameter should already exist in the report, you just need to figure out what it's called. Hopefully it is named something obvious. To create the formula, just right-click on "Formula" and then "New" and put the code there, then save it. Drag your new formula from the Field Explorer into the Report Header.

Comment: @Ryanm I am getting an error that " a number, currency amount, boolean, date, time, string is expected. Do I need to include the {?...} in the code?

Comment: It's working now. Thanks a lot for your prompt response and assistance.